Moving a regression model with Arima errors from R into excel
Hello and thanks in advance for any help.
I'm trying to translate an arima model into an excel spreadsheet for calculations for something I'm studying.
The model is a 4,1,0 model that I used the Arima function in R to fit.
The coefficients are
ar1:.2499
ar2:-.0060
ar3:-.1258
ar4:-.0046
the xreg coefficient is -29.5243.
No matter what I try, I cant seem to get the formula right so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much!
I think I'm getting hung up with which variables I need to difference and which errors to use as inputs as I forecast forward.

Welcome to StackOverflow, Matthew. It looks like you're seeking statistical advice rather than help with programming with R (which this platform is for). If so, please ask over at CrossValidated. If you need support with R, though, please consider this howto and include a minimal reproducible example.
